# iOS: navigate to a view controller not directly connected from the app delegate

Tags: ios, iphone, storyboard, rubymotion

I am building an iOS app and I am facing with an issue which I am finding it a bit difficult to sort out.

The structure of the app is such that I have a MainViewController which is the initial view controller rendered when my app launches. I have built this in storyboard and are connected via segues.

```
MainViewController 
-> UINavigationController
 ->  HomePageViewController
   ->  ContactListViewController
     ->   DetailsViewController
```

My hierarchy would appear as above. The flow works fine in normal cases. Now my case is such that when I receive a push notification, I need to render the DetailsViewController directly.

I know that my push notifications are handled in my app delegate's didReceiveRemoteNotification method. So I have done,

```
def application(application, didReceiveRemoteNotification: userInfo)
  NSLog('Remote notification: %@', userInfo['aps']['alert'])
  push_notification_alert(userInfo)
end

private

def push_notification_alert(userInfo)
  alert = UIAlertView.alloc.initWithTitle( 'Title',
                                         message: userInfo['aps']['alert'],
                                         delegate: self,
                                         cancelButtonTitle: 'Reject',
                                         otherButtonTitles: 'Accept', nil)
  alert.show
end

def alertView(alertView, clickedButtonAtIndex:buttonIndex)
  if(buttonIndex == alertView.cancelButtonIndex)
    ;
  else
    # I need to display the DetailsViewController controller from here. 
  end
end
```

What I am trying to do is that as soon as I receive a push notification, I display an alert to the user which asks him to reject or accept the notification. If he accepts the notification, then I need to display the DetailsViewController.

Hope, you have got the issue. Do put in your inputs and it will of great help.

Comment: What is the problem here? displaying the alert or moving to the DetailsVC?

Comment: The issue is with moving to the DetailsVC

Comment: Is that language totally `Objective-C`?

Comment: The project is in Rubymotion, but does that matter here?

Comment: Since it's tagged with `Objective-C`, it could be...

Comment: Sorry, I have removed that.

Answer (score 1):

Once I found this somewhere in SO, and worked for me. Try this:

```
UIViewController *rootController = (UIViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;
UIViewController *notificationController = [rootController.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"My Push Notification View"];

[rootController presentViewController:notificationController animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

Hope this helps .. :)

Comment: This is how I'd do it. Just make sure to set the Storyboard ID in interface builder as the parameter passed to `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` isn't the class name!

Answer (score 0):

try the following methods,but 3rd method is not recommended because it instantiating new instance unnecessarily if already detailviewcontroller pushed in to the navigation stack

1)get visibleViewcontroller or topViewController and push

```
[navigationController.visibleViewController performSegueWithIdentifier:@"detailview" sender:self];

or

[navigationController.topViewController performSegueWithIdentifier:@"detailview" sender:self];
```

2)performSegue

```
[[[navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0]     performSegueWithIdentifier:@"detailview" sender:self];
```

3)instantiate new instance and push

```
NSString * storyboardName = @"MainStoryboard_iPhone";
NSString * viewControllerID = @"YourID";
UIStoryboard * storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle:nil];
DetailsViewController * controller = (DetailsViewController *)[storyboard    instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:viewControllerID];
[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];

DetailsViewController.yourproperty = @"received push notification";
[yournavigationController pushViewController:DetailsViewController animated:YES];
```

Comment: In the first method, can you please tell which segue will have the identifier 'detailview'? Also, please note that I need to process this controller from the app delegate.

Comment: detailview is the ID for your DetailsViewController. use that code in the else part

Comment: Also, my first root controller is MainViewController and not the NavigationController. Let me try that.